# Indent itemize/enumerate lists with the jfm document class

Tags: enumerate, indentation, itemize

When using the `article` documentclass, `itemize` lists over 2 or more lines automatically indent. However, when using the `jfm` (journal of fluid mechanics) documentclass, they do not. I have the same issue with `enumerate`.

Is there a simple workaround for this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

    \item Long long long Long long long Long long long Long long long Long long long Long long long Long long long Long long long;


\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Outputs the following:

[image]

I want the second line to be indented.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! And where can we have this class?

Comment: @Bernard The class can be found at: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/information/instructions-contributors

Comment: the usual rule with journal classes is that they remove design choices from authors and enforce the publisher style. Are you sure the journal allows you to change the formatting here? (it would be easy to load `enumitem` package and specify a list layout but....)